# How to require two versions of the same package?

Tags: composer-php

in my project i need to use two versions of twitter bootstrap (v2.x and v3.x) 2 for the backend and 3 for the frontend.
is it somehow possible to require both and tell composer to install them in different directoreies?

something like that:

```
   {
       "name": "acme/hello-world",
       "require": {
           "twitter/bootstrap": "2.3.*",
           "twitter/bootstrap": "3.0.* as 'twitter/bootstrap3'" 
       }
   }
```

Comment: You probably should update your software instead to only use Bootstrap 3. Or 2. But not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't require two version, your application should only use one version of a package.

Comment: how do you handle dependencies? dependency a uses b-v1 and you need to use b-v2. but dependency a is discontinued but fully integrated in your php project. so do you instead install b-v1 just because a is not under active development anymore?

Answer (score 2):

If you want you can overwrite the namespace inside loader object. Not exactly having two version at the same time. But maybe you want to use an other version somewhere in your scripts.

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass(\Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::class);
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname($reflection->getFileName()));

$loader->set('Company\\Classname\\', $vendorDir.'/composer/../Other_company/OrOtherClassname/src');
```

Comment: hi @Sjaak Wish "Notice: Undefined variable: loader" how to init object $loader ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use composer-isolation to install a different set of dependencies under a prefixed namespace.

For example you could Have GuzzleHttp and Legasy\GuzzleHttp.

https://github.com/logical-and/composer-isolation