# Composer two packages conflicting on dependency version

Tags: composer-php, guzzle

I already have the [geoip2](https://packagist.org/packages/geoip2/geoip2) package installed. When I installed it some time ago, it required guzzle 3.* so it installed guzzle 3.9.1 as one of its dependencies.

Now I want to install the [predicitonio](https://packagist.org/packages/predictionio/predictionio) package, so I added it to my composer.json

```
"require": {
    ...
    ...
    "geoip2/geoip2": "0.6.*",
    "predictionio/predictionio": "~0.7.1"
}
```

The issue is [predictionio](https://packagist.org/packages/predictionio/predictionio) requires guzzle 3.8.0 or 3.8.1, it won't accept the already installed 3.9.1 version.

I believe [guzzle](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzle/guzzle) 3.8.0 would satisfy both [geoip2](https://packagist.org/packages/geoip2/geoip2) and [predictionio](https://packagist.org/packages/predictionio/predictionio), so the question is how can I downgrade [guzzle](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzle/guzzle), keeping in mind [guzzle](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzle/guzzle) doesn't appear in my composer.json, only the composer.lock.

Below is the output when I run `composer update predictionio/predictionio`

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for predictionio/predictionio ~0.7.1 -> satisfiable by predictionio/predictionio[v0.7.1].
    - Conclusion: remove guzzle/guzzle v3.9.1
    - predictionio/predictionio v0.7.1 requires guzzle/guzzle ~3.8.0 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.8.0, v3.8.1].
    - Can only install one of: guzzle/guzzle[v3.9.1, v3.8.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzle/guzzle[v3.9.1, v3.8.1].
    - Installation request for guzzle/guzzle == 3.9.1.0 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.9.1].
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745560/how-to-require-two-versions-of-the-same-package/76927578#76927578 which has an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to add Guzzle to your `composer.json`. All you have to do is updating Guzzle when you add the new package. (this will downgrade Guzzle to match PredictionIO's requirements)

Simply run

```
composer update predictionio/predictionio guzzle/guzzle
```

As you can see, you can provide multiple packages to `composer update` by separating them with a space. This is described in [the documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I ran `composer update predictionio/predictionio geoip2/geoip2` and it gave the same output as shown in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right. However, running `composer update predictionio/predictionio guzzle/guzzle` should do the trick (I just tested it and it worked for me). I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Some hints related to the question:

By running `composer update named/package`, you only allow this package to be added or it's version increased, but nothing else. The same (but only adding stuff) will happen with `composer require named/package:~1.0` (this is a nice way to add stuff without having to mess with the json formatting).

The most simple solution when updating stuff is to only run `composer update`. Without a package name, ALL packages may be updated.

Updating everything might be a bit risky if you weren't careful with selecting your software packages. Personally I recommend using software that somehow seems to use semantic versioning, which very nicely allows to use the tilde version requirement in Composer. I'd say that everyone should try to use `~X.Y` as the version description, because this allows for both patches as well as compatible updates to be installed.

Libraries you use should allow for enough loosely defined versions of THEIR dependencies. In your example, the `predictionio/predictionio` package requires `guzzle/guzzle:~3.8.0` - they probably have reasons to do so, but in turn force everyone that tries to use their software to use Guzzle 3.8.0 or 3.8.1. I doubt the Guzzle maintainers will break backwards compatibility, because they know they create a very important, basic piece of software that is expected to work, and I think they will receive bug reports pretty soon should they break stuff nonetheless. I would very much like to see the dependencies of any library to allow for compatible updates without restriction, i.e. in this case `~3.8` would be much better.

Avoid depending on branches at all cost. If it is unavoidable to use a branch, assign it an alias version number: `require: { "named/package": "dev-master as 1.2.2" }` If no proper version number can be guessed from earlier releases, start with 0.0.0. That way you can switch to a released version later, which will integrate better into the rest of the version numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install a specific version of a package, you can simply add this to your composer.json in the *require* section:

```
    "guzzle/guzzle" : "3.8.0",
```

And then

```
  composer update guzzle/guzzle
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, haven't tried this but looks like it should work.